# Concatenate many lists of data frame in one data frame

Tags: r

I have a list of many data frame

```
> Data
[[1]]
       [,1]                    [,2]  [,3] [,4]     [,5]    [,6]     [,7]   [,8]        [,9] [,10]   [,11]               [,12]             
  [1,] "EC_VO"                 ""    ""   "388985" "100"   "200701" "1EX4" "PUB_1EEVC" "RE" "1EEVC" "InterfacePublique" "2019-01-17 18:35"
  [2,] "DOUBLON"               ""    ""   "0"      "0"     "200701" "1EX4" "PUB_1EEVC" "RE" "1EEVC" "InterfacePublique" "2019-01-17 18:35"
  [3,] "DIS_CD_MTF"            ""    ""   "235673" "60.59" "200701" "1EX4" "PUB_1EEVC" "RE" "1EEVC" "InterfacePublique" "2019-01-17 18:35"
  [4,] "DIS_CD_MTF"            "00"  ""   "1114"   "0.29"  "200701" "1EX4" "PUB_1EEVC" "RE" "1EEVC" "InterfacePublique" "2019-01-17 18:35"

[[2]]
[1,] "DIS_CD_MTF"            "14"  ""   "94"     "0.02"  "200701" "1EX4" "PUB_1EEVC" "RE" "1EEVC" "InterfacePublique" "2019-01-17 18:35"
 [2,] "DIS_CD_MTF"            "17"  ""   "29819"  "7.67"  "200701" "1EX4" "PUB_1EEVC" "RE" "1EEVC" "InterfacePublique" "2019-01-17 18:35"
 [3,] "DIS_CD_MTF"            "21"  ""   "2621"   "0.67"  "200701" "1EX4" "PUB_1EEVC" "RE" "1EEVC" "InterfacePublique" "2019-01-17 18:35"
 [4,] "DIS_CD_MTF"            "23"  ""   "12277"  "3.16"  "200701" "1EX4" "PUB_1EEVC" "RE" "1EEVC" "InterfacePublique" "2019-01-17 18:35"

[[3]]
[1,] "DIS_CD_RIS"            "053" ""   "29819"  "7.67"  "200701" "1EX4" "PUB_1EEVC" "RE" "1EEVC" "InterfacePublique" "2019-01-17 18:35"
 [2,] "DIS_CD_RIS"            "054" ""   "13112"  "3.37"  "200701" "1EX4" "PUB_1EEVC" "RE" "1EEVC" "InterfacePublique" "2019-01-17 18:35"
 [3,] "DIS_CD_RIS"            "055" ""   "4755"   "1.22"  "200701" "1EX4" "PUB_1EEVC" "RE" "1EEVC" "InterfacePublique" "2019-01-17 18:35"
 [4,] "DIS_CD_RIS"            "058" ""   "10608"  "2.73"  "200701" "1EX4" "PUB_1EEVC" "RE" "1EEVC" "InterfacePublique" "2019-01-17 18:35"
```

I used the `do.call` function to get this result:

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, Data)

   [,1]                    [,2]  [,3] [,4]     [,5]    [,6]     [,7]   [,8]        [,9] [,10]   [,11]               [,12]             
  [1,] "EC_VO"                 ""    ""   "388985" "100"   "200701" "1EX4" "PUB_1EEVC" "RE" "1EEVC" "InterfacePublique" "2019-01-17 18:35"
  [2,] "DOUBLON"               ""    ""   "0"      "0"     "200701" "1EX4" "PUB_1EEVC" "RE" "1EEVC" "InterfacePublique" "2019-01-17 18:35"
  [3,] "DIS_CD_MTF"            ""    ""   "235673" "60.59" "200701" "1EX4" "PUB_1EEVC" "RE" "1EEVC" "InterfacePublique" "2019-01-17 18:35"
  [4,] "DIS_CD_MTF"            "00"  ""   "1114"   "0.29"  "200701" "1EX4" "PUB_1EEVC" "RE" "1EEVC" "InterfacePublique" "2019-01-17 18:35"
  [5,] "DIS_CD_MTF"            "14"  ""   "94"     "0.02"  "200701" "1EX4" "PUB_1EEVC" "RE" "1EEVC" "InterfacePublique" "2019-01-17 18:35"
  [6,] "DIS_CD_MTF"            "17"  ""   "29819"  "7.67"  "200701" "1EX4" "PUB_1EEVC" "RE" "1EEVC" "InterfacePublique" "2019-01-17 18:35"
  [7,] "DIS_CD_MTF"            "21"  ""   "2621"   "0.67"  "200701" "1EX4" "PUB_1EEVC" "RE" "1EEVC" "InterfacePublique" "2019-01-17 18:35"
  [8,] "DIS_CD_MTF"            "23"  ""   "12277"  "3.16"  "200701" "1EX4" "PUB_1EEVC" "RE" "1EEVC" "InterfacePublique" "2019-01-17 18:35"
  [9,] "DIS_CD_RIS"            "053" ""   "29819"  "7.67"  "200701" "1EX4" "PUB_1EEVC" "RE" "1EEVC" "InterfacePublique" "2019-01-17 18:35"
  [10,] "DIS_CD_RIS"            "054" ""   "13112"  "3.37"  "200701" "1EX4" "PUB_1EEVC" "RE" "1EEVC" "InterfacePublique" "2019-01-17 18:35"
  [11,] "DIS_CD_RIS"            "055" ""   "4755"   "1.22"  "200701" "1EX4" "PUB_1EEVC" "RE" "1EEVC" "InterfacePublique" "2019-01-17 18:35"
  [12,] "DIS_CD_RIS"            "058" ""   "10608"  "2.73"  "200701" "1EX4" "PUB_1EEVC" "RE" "1EEVC" "InterfacePublique" "2019-01-17 18:35"
```

But I need the result without using `do.call` function because it's very slow and cause a bug error because I have huge dataset.

Any proposition ? Thanks

**Note** that all data frames have different lengths

Comment: First, those are not data frames but character matrices (so try `rbind` to not cast to dfs). Secondly what does *very slow* mean: 5 mins.? 50 mins.? 5 hrs? Finally, what is the *bug error*?

Comment: @Parfait; thanks for you. well it's a list of 422 matrix and it keep more than 30 minutes. R is crashed any time that I use do.call.

Comment: @Parfait, the issue is here I think `Unset environment variable R_LIBS_USER`

Comment: What is the length of largest matrix -into millions? 422 is not a lot of objects to crash R. Did you use `rbind`: `do.call(rbind, Data)`. How are you calling it? From Rscript? RGui? RStudio? Another IDE?

Comment: @Parfait, yes I called it `do.call(rbind,Data)` and it works very well. I called it from Rstudio. thank you

Comment: @Parfait, yes I used your proposition and it works well I called it from Rstudio. Now the problem is that I have each time this error ** The previous R session was terminated due to an expected crash, you may lost all work space as a result** I do not know why I get this !

Comment: You could convert these matrices to data frames and use `data.table::rbindlist`

Comment: Once again, how large are your matrices?

Comment: Also seeing the data stored in them it seems these should really be data frames as they contain numeric and date time values coerced to character, so it seems you did something wrong upstream. Your objects will also take less memory if not everything is a character.